# Using Python RegEx in Zapier Formatter Extract Pattern

Tags: zapier

I have a field in an RSS item that includes a URL such as:

https://www.facebook.com/9999249845065110

https://www.yelp.com/biz/bix-berkeley-2?hrid=TaFUhHhVrhEJdCPjaB6RUQ

https://www.google.com/search?q=hello%20Signs%20&%20Graphics&ludocid=1720220414695611454#lrd=0x0:0x17df735a614e9c3e,1

I'm trying to setup a Zap in Zapier using the Formatter tool to essentially extract the root domain without the .com. So:

facebook
yelp
google

I have no clue how to use the Formatter Extract Pattern tool though. Can't figure out the syntax.

Best case scenario, it can look at any URL and extract the name of the site (e.g. facebook/google/yelp). If that's too complicated, then I could provide a finite list of what terms to look for and have it return the first (and only) one found. So it would check if the URL contained facebook or google or yelp and if so return that name as a value.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

This is totally possible. The `input` is the text you want to search (the full url) and the `pattern` is your regular expression.

In your case, you want to find the word between `www.` and `.com`. Use the regular expression `www\.(\w+)\.com`.

[image]

That worked for me, and pulled out `yelp`.

You can see each part of the regex explained here: https://regex101.com/r/KmwMAV/1

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Which engine/flavor of Regex is used on Zapier? PCRE, Javascript's, Posix, Java, Python ..?

Comment: Great question. Python!